# Merge [us] and [united-states] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[us](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) and [united-states](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)

I think the later is better; in any case, both are synonymous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The merge has been completed, and the two tags have been set up as synonyms.

---

In response to the comment, as a moderator I'm fine with people suggesting that we manually efect tag synonyms & merges. On a site like Stack Overflow with hundreds of thousands of visitors, the likelihood that enough people who meet criteria (>5 upvotes on tag) will view and vote on tag synonyms is pretty high; on a small site like this it could take forever. Also, we have tools to automatically remap one tag to the other, reducing required work.

That said, you can go [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) to see outstanding merge suggestions and vote on ones you like. For each tag pair, click on the leftmost tag as shown below:

> [image]

From there, you can vote:

> [image]

With that knowledge, in the spirit of mid-1950's organized crime, "vote early, vote often!"

Comment: In the spirit of "teach a man to fish" is there a way to encourage users to vote on tag synonyms? I am not sure we have any that have been created without the use of the diamond mod hammer.

Comment: @StrongBad - updated post with response

Comment: I think we should start using http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/645/vote-on-tag-synonyms in a similar way to how we used http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/215/which-of-these-posts-should-be-deleted